# Python: How to replace strings using ord() and chr() functions instead of built-in string functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Question: Write a program that prints this sentence with only alphabets and spaces without using built-in string methods. You can use `ord()` and `chr()` to solve this question.

**Expected Input/Output**

```
Enter a sentence: I’m 9 years old.
>>> Im years old
```

**My Codes**

```
phrase = "I'm 9 years old."
result = ''
for i in phrase:
    if i == 9:
        result = ord(i) + ord(23)
    elif i == "'":
        result = ord(i) - ord(7)
print(result)
```

**My Output**

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

I tried to identify the problem and fix my codes, but I tried different ways and didn't get the right codes anyway, so I would like some tips and help on solving this question!

Comment: Probably you want to update your result not override? So result +=

Comment: ```ord``` and ```chr``` are builtin functions?

Comment: `ord` takes a `string` as input, not an `int`

Comment: @Nin17 Basically, functions like `str.replace()` are not allowed in this question.

Comment: @Yang what about ```join()``` and ```str.isalpha()```?

Comment: `i == 9` will never be true; you want `i == "9"`.

Comment: @Nin17 It says `ord()` and `chr()` can be used to solve this, so I'm trying to figure it out how to use this method.

Comment: You're also not accumulating anything in `result`; you are *overwriting* its value each time through the loop.

Comment: What's the *exact* problem statement? I don't know if your input and expected output are sufficient to describe what you are supposed to be doing; I certainly don't see any reason why `ord` or `chr` would be useful here.

Comment: @S3DEV clearly I didn't read the post enough, lol. Thanks for pointing that out, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @chepner Sorry for the confusion, I will update the original question statement to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that doesn't use any string methods like `isalpha()` or `replace()`.

```
phrase = "I'm 9 years old."
result = ""
for i in phrase:
    if i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ":
        result += i

print(result)
```

This answer just checks if the character is in a string of allowed characters before adding it to the result.

`ord()` makes the code less clear IMO, but if your teacher wants you to use it you could do this:

```
phrase = "I'm 9 years old."
result = ""
for i in phrase:
    if 123 > ord(i) > 96 or 91 > ord(i) > 64 or ord(i) == 32:
        result += i

print(result)
```

This answer checks if the character's ASCII code corresponds to an alphabetic character or a space.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I've just checked the values of alphabetic characters and learned why it would be this way.